# How to attach python code to a question

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

I'm newbie to Stack Overflow as well as programming. I just wanted to know what is the best way to attach a code to a question.

I know that indenting by 4 spaces treats a line as code .. but if I have a block of code then its becoming a pain to indent each and every line by four spaces. Blocking a set and pressing tab also does not seem to work. I know that I'm missing something here.

Just wanted experienced users to shed some light on this.

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)

Answer (score 2):

Mark some text in the question/answer editor, then press the "code" button on the toolbar (`{}`). It will indent your selection as necessary.